# Unknown shortcut "and Insert Terminator + LF"

Tags: aptana

Using Aptana Studio 3 and when using the shortcut <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> to insert a line above the current line, Aptana will ask offer a drop-down with the following options:

- `and Insert Terminator + LF`
- `Insert Line Above Current Line`

I want `Insert Line Above Current` only but have been unable to find where to change this key code.

Comment: Good luck. I don't think it's maintained anymore.

Comment: Aptana Studio 3 is actively maintained and worked on. I'm not sure what you are referring to.

Comment: @Ingo - Last I had heard several months ago, Aptana was not actively working on any of their software. I use Aptana Studio 2; so far, no prompt for a Studio 3 upgrade? I don't think I am the only one.

Comment: Ah. No--that's completely wrong. Check out the Aptana GitHub activity. Aptana Studio is the core of the new Titanium Studio for Appcelerator, so it's getting lots of love and support. We can't automatically upgrade users from Aptana 2 to 3 (it's an Eclipse thing) but perhaps we need to better about letting Studio 2 users know. Thanks for reminding us of that.

Comment: @Ingo - My apologies if I got it wrong, all I can evaluate is what I have seen in front of me. I just tried to update my Aptana Studio, and I didn't get any update to a new system/setup. I honestly thought that Aptana and their products were defunct.

Comment: I understand exactly how you got that impression. We'll fix that.

Comment: @Ingo - Sorry bro; I imagine that's frustrating. I still use Aptana 2 all the time; if I could pitch a single support issue, can you support WebDAV and WebDAV HTTPS? :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That top option appears to be coming from a key binding in Commands > Source > Move to EOL > "Insert Terminator + LF". Due to a Eclipse peculiarity, those key bindings are not listed in the default key binding preference.

To remove, you have to edit the bundle. It's pretty simple:

1. Commands > Source > Edit this Bundle. It will create a project in your workspace
2. Look in the commands folder of that project for the proper command (it should be pretty obvious)
3. Comment out or change the keybinding. You *might* have to restart.

For more info, see: http://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/Modifying+your+shortcut+keys#Modifyingyourshortcutkeys-ModifyingtheBuiltInBundles

Comment: That was it.  Thanks for the walk-through